# Record and preview webcamera stream at the same time

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg and Windows 7/10 OS and going to save webcamera stream to file and preview it at the same time (from time to time, not constantly).
I can solve each of these tasks separately:

1. Saving webcamera stream to 1-minute files:

`$ffmpeg_exe = "C:\ffmpeg.exe"`

`$video_source = "USB Video Device"`

``` Start-Process $ffmpeg_exe -ArgumentList @("-y -hide_banner -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M -i video=``"$video_source``" -preset ultrafast -strftime 1 -f segment -segment_time 00:01:00 ``"$out_folder\%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.mp4``"") -Wait -NoNewWindow ```

2. Preview webcamera using ffplay:

`$ffplay_exe = "C:\ffplay.exe"`

``` Start-Process $ffplay_exe -ArgumentList @("-hide_banner -f dshow -i video=``"$video_source``" -preset ultrafast") -Wait -NoNewWindow ```

Is there a way to do it using single command? I think I have to use ffmpeg  within named pipes but I don't understand how to create/operate them. Maybe someone have already working Windows command which will 1) save webcamera video to file 2) also send it to named pipe for another applications like ffplay or VLC?

Thanks for your answers,

--Vlad

Comment: What's wrong with doing it with two commands?

Comment: >>stream to file and preview it at the same time (from time to time, not constantly):

Windows (or ffmpeg?) doesn't support simultaneous access to webcamera from 2 apps (like ffmpeg and ffplay)